# How do I copy my Sharepoint list schema from one list to another?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have two sites and two lists:

```
Site A
List A
```

and

```
Site B
List B
```

I want to copy the schema from `List A` to `List B`... how do I do this?

I have managed to copy the list from `Site A` to `Site B` in it's initial creation using PnP PowerShell, however, I am seemingly unable to figure out how to update the list should the schema of the list change.

I have tried using a variety of Powershell commands but with no luck.

Comment: Do you have any live data in the "List B"? If not, recreate List B by following: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-new-list-based-on-the-columns-in-another-list-49666e8c-8c48-414f-8e5e-dc0e232acd27. Let me know if it works for you.